# Angular 2: why doesn't routerLink add "router-link-active" class to links in my directive template?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is a stripped down version of my main component that's bootstrapped, defining one route.

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
import {
    RouteConfig,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
} from "angular2/router";

import { DashboardComponent } from "./components/dashboard/dashboard.component";

@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    useAsDefault: true,
  },
])
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "app/app.component.html",
  directives: [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
  ],
  providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

and in the corresponding HTML for the main component, the router-link-active class is added to the active link.

```
<nav class="global-navigation">
    <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">View All</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Tag',{tagName:'CSS'}]">CSS</a>
</nav>
<main class="main-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

The dashboard component:

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
import { NotesList } from "../../components/notes-list/notes-list.component";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from "angular2/router";

@Component({
  selector: "my-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "app/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.html",
  directives: [NotesList, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class DashboardComponent {}
```

in the dashboard HTML, the router-link-active class is not added to the active link.

```
<orbital-notes-list></orbital-notes-list>

<a [routerLink]="['Tag', {tagName:'CSS'}]">Testing</a>
<a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Back</a>
```

I can't find a solution. I'm surely missing something.

Comment: Not sure, but I think [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5334) reports what you're seeing.

Comment: The issue that @EricMartinez referred to is that, it does add the class `route-link-active` but to all the child routes and occurs if you have nested routes. Do you ?

Comment: have you really checked with DOM? are you sure it doesn't add `route-link-active` really?

Comment: So to clarify, the router-link-active class works as expected in my main component template. The links work and router-link-active class is added to the active link. My main component configures 2 routes including "/dashboard" (I removed one of the routes to simplify the code). In my DashboardComponent template, I'm listing 2 links with [routerLink] and again the links work, the only problem is that the router-link-active class is not added. It's weird, it's gotta be something simple, as I'm just getting started with Angular2. router-link-active is definitely not added in the route

Comment: *definitely not added in the DashboardComponent template